# heroku redis connection issues using sidekiq

Tags: heroku, sidekiq

I am using Sidekiq to process jobs. I am using Heroku basic plan which allows up to 40 connections. My understanding is that each thread can have up to 1 connection. Sidekiq has a default number of threads of 25. In my thinking I should never be getting more than 25 connections.

But I have been getting too many connections errors to redis. How would this be posible? Should I cut down the number of Sidekiq workers? Or is there something else I can do? I currently have my Procfile like this:

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

Would switching it to this fix it?

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 10
```

Is it possible Sidekiq is not closing connections properly? Also, when I get this "too many connections" error, it basically brings down the site - is there a way to let if fail gracefully which it seems like it should do.

Comment: Yes, `-c 10` is a reasonable thing to do and will help.

Comment: thx @MikePerham, is there any way that Sidekiq could create more connections than it's processor to use limit? I think that's my confusion.

Comment: Sure, if you are spinning up your own threads somehow.  For instance the `Timeout` module will spin up threads silently.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer was that heroku wasn't accurately showing the number of connections which was tripping up any debugging. And I was pretty amateurish in figuring it out since Redis has pretty much worked.

My timeout was set to zero (determined via >`heroku redis:info`) which basically meant that connections are held open indefinitely (the dashboard didn't show this accurately saying I was using like 10 when really having like 35).

Connecting to redis via heroku redis:cli and then running `>CLIENT LIST` showed the problem where there were many connections / clients probably in like TIME_WAIT state.

changing the timeout fixed this:

```
heroku redis:timeout --seconds 60
```

Honestly, calling it a connection pool is a big inaccurate.